# Python: Next() Keeps giving error StopIteration

Tags: python, iterator

I am having some trouble with my code for an assignment where I am supposed to go through a text file and find birthdays that are in april and print them. Here is what the text file looks like:
Bob, June 10
Joe, April 12
Sue, July 22
I am supposed to go through it and print out the name and birthdays in april but I keep getting e = next(a) StopIteration. I am really confused!

```
a = open("c:/Users/me/Documents/fruits.txt", "r")
for k in a:
    e = next(a)
    b = e.strip()
    c = b[0 : 5]
    if c == "April":
       print b
       e = next(a)
   else:
    e = next(a)
a.close()
```

Comment: Why are you using both `for k in a` and `e = next(a)`? Both do essentially the same thing. BTW, `StopIteration` means that you have reached the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

This code will iterate through the lines of the file and print any line with "April" in it. When you are iterating through the lines of a file, you do not need to call next() in the loop body.

```
for line in open("fruits.txt"):
    if "April" in line:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Wow!~ That was actually very simple! Thanks for pointing this out and teaching me! :P